# why my foreach loop did not working?

Tags: php

i need help, i need to mail via php mail function so in the message field i should make a HTML text, but in this text i have loop to count an array to echo the table with it's data, but something goes wrong, is there anybody to know why it doesn;t work???

```
public function sendmail($arr){
    $to = $_SESSION['email'];
    $subject = 'کارت شارژ';
    $message = '<html>
                    <head>
                      <title>کد شارژ خریداری شده شما</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                      <p>از خرید شما متشکریم</p>
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>#شماره</th><th>کد شارژ</th>
                        </tr>
                        '+ 
                        foreach ($arr as $i){
                            echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
                        }
                            +'
                      </table>
                    </body>
                </html>';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'To: '.$_SESSION['phone'].' <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: hameja123 <hameja123@hameja123.ir>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: You can't throw a loop in the middle of a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just splice code into a string like that. Besides, `+` is for adding, not concatenating.

Try precomputing the rows:

```
$rows = "";
foreach($arr as $i) $rows .= "<tr><td>".$i."</td></tr>";
```

Then you can concatenate it in:

```
"...... ".$rows." .......";
```

Comment: Kolnik thanks it works but there in another problem, when the mail function done , there is no mail in my email mailbox, why? could you give me hand?

Answer (score 0):

Change part of your code to:

```
$data = '';
foreach ($arr as $i){
    $data .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
}
$message = '<html>
                <head>
                  <title>کد شارژ خریداری شده شما</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                  <p>از خرید شما متشکریم</p>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#شماره</th><th>کد شارژ</th>
                    </tr>
                    '.$data.'
                  </table>
                </body>
            </html>';
```

You cannot insert foreach inline with string.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use

```
foreach ($arr as $i){
                            echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
                        }
```

inside the "$message =" statement.

Instead, do this before  `$message = '<html>`

```
$string='';
foreach($arr as $i)
$string = $string.'<tr><td>$i</td><tr>';
```

Now, inside the $message=,

Do this:

```
<tr>
                          <th>#شماره</th><th>کد شارژ</th>
                        </tr>
                        $string
                      </table>
```